# Is there a difference between type=ethernet and type=802-3-ethernet in network-manager connection configuration?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I'm changing my network configuration from `interfaces` to `network-manager` (with files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connection`) and encountered `type=802-3-ethernet` and `type=ethernet` in connection files on different machines which must have been created with the `nm` applet on unknown Ubuntu version before 17.04. Both seem to work.

I ran `nmcli -f GENERAL.TYPE device show` following `man NetworkManager.conf` and only saw `ethernet` as supported type. Does it make a difference? I don't want to guess that it does not from trying both since I want to do it right and thus understand what I'm doing.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type=802-3-ethernet and type=ethernet is identical, one is an alias. Both work.

nm-applet is not used to modify/create connections. nm-connection-editor is.

No client application (like nm-connection-editor) ever directly writes those files. They are owned by root, and written by NetworkManager.

It might be a good idea to use NM client tools (nmcli, nmtui, nm-connection-editor) instead of editing files by hand. But both works.

`nmcli device` is about networking interfaces. It is not the same as connection profiles (`nmcli connection`, /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections).

`man NetworkManager.conf` is mostly about NetworkManager's configuration files, again not about connection profiles. See `man nm-settings` and `man nm-settings-keyfile`.

Answer (score 1):

[thaller's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/912595/28965):

> type=802-3-ethernet and type=ethernet is identical, one is an alias. Both work.

They definitely aren't completely interchangeable.

```
$ nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 1.14.6
```

Here are some peculiarities I observed.

If we use full `setting.property` keys, `802-3-ethernet` is a valid value but `ethernet` is not. And when providing a value of `802-3-ethernet`, `ethernet` is written to the file.

```
$ nmcli connection add \
    connection.id "Test" \
    connection.type "ethernet" \
    connection.interface-name ""
Error: invalid connection type; ethernet.
$ nmcli connection add \
    connection.id "Test" \
    connection.type "802-3-ethernet" \
    connection.interface-name ""
Connection 'Test' (…) successfully added.
$ nmcli connection show Test | grep connection.type
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
$ grep type /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Test.nmconnection 
type=ethernet
$ nmcli connection delete Test
```

If we use the [Property Aliases](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html#property_aliases) as keys, both `802-3-ethernet` and `ethernet` are valid values. `ethernet` is written to the file in both cases.

```
$ nmcli connection add con-name "Test" type "802-3-ethernet" ifname ""
Connection 'Test' (…) successfully added.
$ grep type /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Test.nmconnection 
type=ethernet
$ nmcli connection delete Test
$ nmcli connection add con-name "Test" type "ethernet" ifname ""
Connection 'Test' (…) successfully added.
$ grep type /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Test.nmconnection 
type=ethernet
```

If we are using the interactive `nmcli` we can use either. Tab completion worked for the word `802-3-ethernet` but not for `ethernet`.

```
$ nmcli connection edit "Test"
nmcli> set 802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate yes
nmcli> print 802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate 
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate: yes
nmcli> set ethernet.auto-negotiate no
nmcli> print ethernet.auto-negotiate 
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate: no
```

Conclusion: NetworkManager's de/serialisation is inconsistent. If manually editing a file I would stick to `ethernet`. If attempting to script anything with `nmcli` be sure to test it, whichever you choose.

Comment: I encountered this issue with a fresh Debian 12 install as well. Seems like the autoconfiguration inserted "802-3-ethernet" into the connection profile file somehow... switching to "ethernet" resolved the problem.